# Compiling the output from the Perl Compiler (B::C), I get “EXTERN.h: No such file or directory”

Tags: debian, perl, compiler

If I try to compile something generated by [`B::C`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::C),

```
$ perl -MO=C,-omyTest.c -e'print "Hello World!";'
-e syntax OK
```

And then run `gcc myTest

```
$ gcc ./myTest.c 
./myTest.c:3:10: fatal error: EXTERN.h: No such file or directory
 #include "EXTERN.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indicator that you need `libperl`

```
$ apt-file search EXTERN.h
libperl5.28: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1/CORE/EXTERN.h
```

You can add that package with

```
$ sudo apt-get install libperl5.28
```

You must then add that list to your path when you invoke GCC with (`-I`),

```
gcc -I"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.28.1/CORE/" -lperl ./myTest.c
```